# Drawing a diagonal line on a word

Tags: symbols, arrows

I want to draw a diagonal line on a word in latex(meaning that I now ignore that word) How is it possible? What about diagonal arrows?

Comment: Are you aware of the cancel package?

Comment: some useful information here: [How do I strike through the first text on a line using the cancel module?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/302882/579)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}
 Happy New Year! Good bye \cancel{2017}!
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for the arrow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}
Happy New Year! Good bye \cancel{2017}! 

Forget about $\cancelto{~}{2016}$, and don't even mention \xcancel{2015}!
\end{document}
```

[image]

To put words on top of the crossed out words, you may use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\StrikeAndReplace}[2]{\tikz[baseline=(old.base)]{\node(old){#1};
\draw[-] (old.south west)--(old.north east);
\node[above of=old,node distance=4mm] {#2};}}
\begin{document}
Happy New Year! Good bye \cancel{2017}! 

Forget about $\cancelto{~}{2016}$, and don't even mention \xcancel{2015}!

New Year's resolution: No more $\stackrel{\displaystyle\text{vegetables}}{\cancel{\text{junk food}}}$!

With Ti\emph{k}Z: \StrikeAndReplace{SUV car}{bike}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Undoubtedly, there are more options, and/or the Ti*k*Z command can be tuned according to one's needs.

Comment: very nice example (+1)! happy new year!

Comment: Thanks a lot: for your nice answer and also congratulating new year. Happy new year to you!

Comment: One more question: I wanted to cancel a word, but it seems that \cancel is for math environment. However I just put the word in a text box in $$. But now I am trying to put another word above the canceled word. Is that possible? (I mean replacing a word by another one)